# Using customized images for the nodes in alloy theme definition

Tags: alloy

Alloy theme definition interface allows to assign a customized image for each signature. It is possible to choose an image from a list of predefined images. But, I am wondering if it is possible to add my own image to this list?!

[image: Here is an screenshot of the list I mean.]

Comment: Note that strictly speaking these are shapes that GraphViz knows how to draw, not images used as is.  (If you are interested in customizing the display of particular instances, e.g. for publication, you may want to export the instance in XML or GraphViz format; you can then do what you like with the description of the instance.  I've done this to tweak the layout.  But it's not the same as having the visualizer use a custom shape, of course.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alloy source code is available and you may edit it to your needs. 
The source code is included in the jar you use to run the Alloy Analyzer.

There is no built-in customization to do this.

Comment: The documentation of [Alloy API](http://alloy.mit.edu/alloy/documentation/alloy-api/index.html) could help you.